# Imitate crop function of system Gallery

Tags: android, gallery

i want to Imitate crop function of system Gallery as the pic http://i.6.cn/cvbnm/88/4a/be/94d8630ca9a3261154f0acf2ebd9f39d.png   ,i have found the souce code ,at  Gallery\src\com\android\camera , but i cannot add the edit rectangular on one pic,i know the  edit rectangular is finiehed  in the HighlightView.jave file.can you tell me how to add a edit rectangular on the pic,which can scale and move like edit rectangular

Answer (score 1):

1.Fire the intent

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
  intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(IMAGE_PATH_TO_SAVE_CROPPED_IMAGE)));
  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), RETURN_CODE);
```

2.Then in onActivityResult

```
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(IMAGE_PATH_TO_SAVE_CROPPED_IMAGE);
  // bitmap will contain the cropped image
```

Comment: your method is call system ,my mean is  using source code to finish same effect.thank you for your answer